# Google sheet importxml xpath query

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

I'm trying to get the data for "Next Earnings Announcement" for this http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/1880:HK site.

I have tried

`=ImportXml( "http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/1880:HK", "//span[@class='company_stat']" )`

`=ImportXml( "http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/1880:HK", "/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[16]/td/text()" )`

getting a `#N/A`, want `10/27/2014` as result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of your fragile, horribly complicated XPath expression, try a useful one:

```
//th[normalize-space() = 'Next Earnings Announcement']/following-sibling::td
```